# Trailing white space

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, removing-whitespace

I have a trailing white space I am curious on how to get rid of, tried a few different methods. This is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output 
 indent="no"
 method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/"> 
Famous Mountains of the World
<xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mountain">
Mountain Name:<xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>
Mountain Name:(<xsl:value-of select="name[@language='PigLatin'] "/>)
Location:<xsl:value-of select="location"/>
Height:<xsl:value-of select="height"/></xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is how I am trying to get it to put out.

```
Mountain Name:Mount Everest
Mountain Name:(ountMa verestEa)
Mountain Name:Mount Ranier
Mountain Name:()
Mountain Name:Mount St. Helens
Mountain Name:()
```

Instead it puts out:

```
Mountain Name:Mount Everest
Mountain Name:(ountMa verestEa)
Mountain Name:Mount Ranier
Mountain Name:()
Mountain Name:Mount St. Helens
Mountain Name:()
```

or

```
   Mountain Name:Mount Everest
Mountain Name:(ountMa verestEa)
Mountain Name:Mount Ranier
Mountain Name:()
Mountain Name:Mount St. Helens
Mountain Name:()
```

if I use the xsl:text and xsl:strip-space elements="*" hasnt helped deal with the indent.

Any idea on how to get rid of the extra space?Any help would be a great help. Been bugging me for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that the linebreaks in your XSLT are being interpreted as literal linebreaks in your output. Try either wrapping text output in `xsl:text` or using `concat()` in your `xsl:value-of`.

For example, instead of:

```
Mountain Name:<xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>
```

Try either this:

```
<xsl:text>Mountain Name:</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name[@language='English'] "/>
```

or this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Mountain Name:',name[@language='English'])"/>
```

Comment: I tried <xsl:text> earlier but it causes an indention on the first line I can't for the life of me get rid of. I will try concat instead.

Comment: You should use this in combination with the `xsl:strip-space`

Comment: Hmmm yea that's still not working that indention will not go away, that's what I have been stuck on the last bit.  Just shows up for the first line of the node. Anyhow thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding [`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) inside the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag. Telling xslt to strip space won't cause it to strip *all* whitespace, but I think it will achieve what you want. For more granular control over whitespace you can give it a list of specific elements, or even use the `normalize-space()` xpath predicate.

Comment: Much appreciated I will give that shot, I tried the <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> I will tinker with it some more. Thanks again.

Comment: Eh beats me still not doing it.

Comment: `xsl:strip-space` applies to _elements_ that only contain whitespace-only text nodes. It will not affect elements with other content than that. So, `normalize-space()` is not really a more granular version of it, but a different function alltogether.

Comment: I didn't say `normalize-space` was a more granular *version* of anything. I said you could achieve more granular control over xslt's whitespace output by using it.